# Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem

Tags: ios, xcode

While creating ssl certificate and private certificate for apple push notification,i used to follow raywenderlich.com steps .Going good with steps creating and configuring certificate for push notification,but i stick with a place  "Enter pass phrase for PushKey.pem".i used to enter the pass phrase which i given in previous step for this key.it always says the pass is too small and character minimum 4 to 1024,i entered a 5 characters.but the same pass phrase not accepting in this steps...any body help me...i'm new to iOS

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey1.pem
Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:
575:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:850:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
```

Thanks

iniyan

Answer (score 0):

When you finished create CSR file, if you go to the Keys section of Keychain Access, you will see that a new private key has appeared in your keychain. Right click it and choose Export.

Make sure that you used this p12 file to push notification.

You could create new CSR file if need!

TUT:http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Good luck!